# Disable text box until check box is checked

Tags: vb.net, vba

Im trying to disable the textBoxNo until the chkBox is checked. This works only after the first check. I need to make the txtBox unavailable until checked.

```
'In the event of any change in checkbox
Private Sub chkBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBox.CheckedChanged
    'Enable textbox if Box tickets are required
    If chkBox.Checked = True Then
        txtBoxNo.Enabled = True
    Else txtBoxNo.Enabled = False
        txtBoxNo.Text = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: _txtBoxNo.Enabled =  chkBox.Checked_ nothing else

Comment: or _txtBoxNo.Enabled = Not chkBox.Checked_ depending on how your logic works

Comment: @Steve if you look at the code, Gerry also wants to clear the contents of the textbox, and neither of the lines of code in your comment will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want the textbox to be disabled every time you start the program, in Visual Studio, open the form's UI designer where you can addd all you controls etc.

Click on the textbox that you want to have disabled until the checkbox is checked.

If you have the standard Visual studio setup, in the lower right hand side of the Visual Studio, you should see a list of the textbox's properties.

Find the one that says "Enabled". To the right, it should say that the property is True. This means that by default the textbox is enabled. Sorry if this seems simple, but I'm just taking it step by step.

Now. There are a couple of ways you can change it, but the simplest way of changing True/False properties such as "Enabled" is just to double click on "Enabled"

In the future, every time you run the program, the textbox should be disabled until you enable it in your code.